# Como criar esse efeito na imagem?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Como faço para criar esse efeito na parte de baixo da imagem? Eu consegui fazer criando uma div com bordas, mas não se ajusta corretamente na parte da responsividade.

Algum exemplo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No caso é duplicada da outra, basta inverter os valores que vc vai ter a "seta" apontando para sima

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a propriedade *clip-path*.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title> </title>
 <style> 
  .teste{
   background: url('https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/thumbnail/HPWsSXb4xiwrj8lkx/videoblocks-tropical-beach-background-loop_bhjouqunm_thumbnail-full01.png') no-repeat center;
   -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 51% 71%, 0% 75%, 0 0);
   clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 51% 71%, 0% 75%, 0 0);
   
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="teste"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rapaz, perfeito, nunca tinha ouvido falar dessa propriedade.. Muito obg.

Comment: @Wendler Esse site ajuda a criar formas com *clip-path* https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/